# Calculating the number of permutations whose sum makes N where only single digits are allowed

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

If we want to know the number of ways that $N$ can be made by taking the sum of $T$ numbers we can use $\dfrac{(N+(T-1))!}{(N!\times (T-1)!)}$ however, how would you be able to calculate the number of ways that $N$ can be made by taking the sum of $T$ numbers where all numbers are only single digit numbers?

Comment: Could you explain more specifically what you mean by "making $N$ by taking the sum of $T$ numbers"? I can't think of any interpretation of this formulation in which your count of $\frac{(N+T)!}{N!T!}$ would be correct for $T=1$.

Comment: My mistake @joriki, The formula uses T-1 instead of T. I am trying to calculate the number of ways I can create the number N by summing T numbers e.g. if N = 11 and T = 2 permutations are 6+5, 5+6, 4+7, 7+4, 3+8, 8+3, 2+9, 9+2, 10+1, 1+10, 11+0, 0+11 however I want to discount the last 4 permutations because one of the numbers is a 2 digit number so in this case I would expect the formula to output 8 because there are 8 combinations not including the last 4 permutations.